# Why must $c$ equal $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Axler's: *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

> [image]

I guess I understand that $b=0$ because otherwise we would have:

$$T(0,0,0)=(b,0)$$

That is, it doesn't take $0_{R^3}$ to $0_{R^2}$. But I can't figure out why $c=0$ must be true. Could you give me only a hint? I don't want a full answer. (Unless the hint can only be the *full answer*).

Comment: Have you check when $T((x+x_1, y+y_1, z+z_1)) = T(x, y, z) +T(x_1, y_1, z_1)$

Comment: @JackyChong Ah. Got it. From my naive intuition, I didn't think at first that this would be the problem. If you want, insert it as an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: It's okay. I don't need the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Notice that in the second component of the image, the parameter $c$ multiplies a non-linear term: $xyz$.

Answer (score 1):

You want $T(2,2,2)=2T(1,1,1)$.